# How to change gcc version linux

Tags: linux, gcc, version, proc

I have gcc-4.6 & gcc-4.7 both installed on my machine and I made gcc the default compiler. But still I could see 4.6 under "cat /proc/version" but I want 4.7 in place of 4.6.

```
cat /proc/version 
Linux version 3.2.0-4-rt-686-pae (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2
```

How can I change gcc version here from 4.6 to 4.7 ?

Any help would be really helpfull for me.

Many Thanks.

Comment: `/proc/version` shows the compiler used to compile the kernel. What made you think it had anything to do with what compilers you have installed?

Comment: Actually I have one module which is loaded in kernel  with gcc 4.7 , but I want that same module to be compiled with gcc 4.6 while loading different kernel which has gcc 4.6 as default. So my idea is that if I change gcc 4.6 to gcc 4.7 then the same module can compile in the other kernel also.

Comment: To *change* `/proc/version` you'll have to get or compile a new kernel.

Comment: Is there any way  to use a module in 3.2  which is compiled with kernel 3.10 ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have both versions installed,and 4.6 being treated as the default.
The easiest way make gcc-4.7 the default gcc is to move the symlink of /usr/bin/gcc:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/gcc

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 /usr/bin/gcc
```

Reference link [here](http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/2011-12-24_GCCv47/)

Comment: I have already tried with the commands you provided, but still there is no change, cat /proc/version shows gcc 4.6.3.  But one more point here is when i give gcc --version it shows 4.7 only. I dont understand how do i change in /proc/version

Comment: @linuxman What makes you think you want to change `/proc/version`?! (See my comment to the question.)

Comment: Basically i have two kernels in my machine i.e 3.2 and 3.10. Due to some problems I would like to use 3.2 kernel for my job, but when i use 3.2 kernel one of my  library is not loading and during boot i am getting this error"disagrees about version of symbol module_layout".

Comment: @linuxman This indicates you have compiled the module against a different version of the kernel than is running

Answer (score 0):

As the same problem is mentioned here https://askubuntu.com/questions/193539/having-2-versions-of-gcc 
I suggest you to check the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to use a module in 3.2 which is compiled with kernel
>   3.10 ?

You can try the option `-f` of `modprobe`.