# Configure error installing fftw

Tags: gcc, openmp, fftw

I just followed the instructions [here](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/05/10/compiling-gcc-6-mac-os-x/) to update my gcc. Now I am trying to install FFTW. So I downloaded the filed [here](http://www.fftw.org/download.html). After I unzip and navigate to that directory I run this:

```
./configure  --enable-mpi --enable-threads --enable-openmp
```

But I get the following error:

```
checking for OpenMP flag of C compiler... unknown
configure: error: don't know how to enable OpenMP
```

I know OpenMP didn't work before I updated GCC, but it does now if I do this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/gcc-6.1.0/bin:$PATH
gcc-6.1.0 main.c -o main
```

So I'm guessing the problem is that when I try to configure FFTW it is using the default gcc, but I need it to use gcc-6.1.0. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Installation-on-Unix.html), `CC` is the environment variable to set the compiler for `configure`.

```
./configure CC=gcc-6.1.0 --enable-mpi --enable-threads --enable-openmp
```

should set the version of gcc for that `configure`.  You can also consider [changing the symbolic link for gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29144317/5894196).

Comment: +1 for setting CC variable **after** configure. This is a good practice, since it will appear on the first lines of `config.log` file.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of setting PATH should work if you also set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the lib or lib64 which was installed along with your new gcc. It should be in the same directory as bin.