# Issue compiling FFTW

Tags: gcc, clang, mpi, openmpi, fftw

I am trying to install FFTW on my mac with OpenMP enabled. I initially had trouble configuring, but that issue was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39542979/configure-error-installing-fftw/39546224#39546224).

Now after configuring I type "make" and I get the following error:

```
libtool: compile:  mpicc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../kernel -I../dft -I../rdft -I../api -I../tests -I../libbench2 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -mtune=native -malign-double -fstrict-aliasing -fno-schedule-insns -ffast-math -Wa,-q -Wl,-no_compact_unwind -MT any-true.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/any-true.Tpo -c any-true.c -o any-true.o
clang: error: unknown argument: '-malign-double'
clang: warning: -Wl,-no_compact_unwind: 'linker' input unused
clang: error: unsupported argument '-q' to option 'Wa,'
clang: warning: optimization flag '-fno-schedule-insns' is not supported
make[3]: *** [any-true.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What is the issue here and how can I solve it?

Comment: how exactly did you invoke the `configure` script?

Comment: ./configure CC=gcc-6.1.0 --enable-mpi --enable-threads --enable-openmp

Comment: and this version of `gcc` was installed manually?

Comment: yes that was my first issue, I couldn't get anything OpenMP to work, but now it is

Comment: Your error messages are coming from clang, which is not consistent with your supposed ./configure with gcc-6.1.0

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Do I need to update clang?

Comment: Please, add the faulty `mpicc` line that you showed in the chat. That would help people finding/understanding the issue in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try passing the location of the gcc compiler its absolute path rather than the binary name, just as

```
CC=/usr/local/gcc-6.1.0/bin/gcc-6.1.0 ./configure --enable-mpi --enable-threads --enable-openmp
```

**EDIT**
After having a brief chat with OP, it looks like he omitted part of the error and the error came from the `mpicc` compiler used (due to `--enable-mpi` in the configure stage). According to the user, they were using OpenMPI and according to this [FAQ](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=mpi-apps#override-wrappers-after-v1.0) the user can tune the C compiler by using the `OMPI_CC` environtment variable. So my suggestion was to build the FFTW library as

```
OMPI_CC=/usr/local/gcc-6.1.0/bin/gcc-6.1.0 make
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried this and I get the error:    configure: error: in `/Users/myusername/Desktop/fftw-3.3.5':

Comment: Can you share some more lines that surround the error?

Comment: Of course: configure: error: in `/Users/myusername/Desktop/fftw-3.3.5':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

Comment: Can you check whether `/usr/local/gcc-6.1.0/bin/gcc` exists?

Comment: Simply run `ls -la /usr/local/gcc-6.1.0/bin/gcc`

Comment: Looks like it doesn't: ls: /usr/local/gcc-6.1.0/bin/gcc: No such file or directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123719/discussion-between-harald-and-user906357).